# How to add third party libraries/frameworks in Xamarin.iOS project?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, nuget, libraries, nuget-package

I want to add a third party library/framework in my Xamarin project (iOS). In native iOS I can use Cocoa pods or Carthage. What is the equivalent of that here. How to do it ? Is Nuget the only solution for that or is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can binding an Objective-C library by Objective Sharpie.You can access this link to get more useful information. https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/